# Algorithm to find isomorphic set of permutations

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, permutation

I have an array of set of permutations, and I want to remove isomorphic permutations.

> We have `S` sets of permutations, where each set contain `K` permutations, and each permutation is represented as and array of `N` elements. I'm currently saving it as an array `int pset[S][K][N]`, where `S`, `K` and `N` are fixed, and N is larger than K.
>
> Two sets of permutations, `A` and `B`,  are **isomorphic**, if there exists a permutation `P`, that converts elements from `A` to `B` (for example, if `a` is an element of set `A`, then `P(a)` is an element of set `B`).  In this case we can say that **`P` makes `A` and `B` isomorphic**.

My current algorithm is:

1. We choose all pairs `s1 = pset[i]` and `s2 = pset[j]`, such that `i < j`
2. Each element from choosen sets (`s1` and `s2`) are numered from `1` to `K`. That means that each element can be represented as `s1[i]` or `s2[i]`, where `0 < i < K+1`
3. For every permutation `T` of `K` elements, we do the following:

   - Find the permutation `R`, such that `R(s1[1]) = s2[1]`
   - Check if `R` is a permutation that make `s1` and `T(s2)` isomorphic, where `T(s2)` is a rearrangement of the elements (permutations) of the set `s2`, so basically we just check if `R(s1[i]) = s2[T[i]]`, where `0 < i < K+1`
   - If not, then we go to the next permutation `T`.

This algorithms works really slow: `O(S^2)` for the first step, `O(K!)` to loop through each permutation `T`, `O(N^2)` to find the `R`, and `O(K*N)` to check if the `R` is the permutation that makes `s1` and `s2` isomorphic - so it is `O(S^2 * K! * N^2)`.

> Question: Can we make it faster?

Comment: I think you can improve `K!` multiplier to polynomial: for every i and j: find permutation R such that R(s1[i]) = s2[j], mark j as "used", then for every k != i, find a non-"used" m, such that R(s1[k]) = s2[m], and mark m as "used". If for some i and j you can "mark" all `m` from 1 to K, then R makes s1 and s2 isomorphic.

Comment: How stable does this has to be? You could sort them all, O(n*mlgm), where n is the number of sequences and m is the length of the sequence. Then you can add them all to a set, which (if compare is O(m)) will be O(n*lg(n)*m), making the total cost O(n*m*lg(n))).

Comment: Is the definition of the problem correctly expressed? Because I think you should write "...if there exists a ``function`` ``P``, that converts elements from ``A`` to ``B`` and viceversa..."

Comment: @frenk I think the function is induced by a permutation, i.e. `Pa` is defined as a permutation `p` composed with `a`.

Comment: I'm agree with you, by the way in the definition it should be added the piece "... and  ``viceversa``...". Just another thing, do you consider the sets ``{123,111,321}`` and ``{321,333,123}`` isomorphic?

Comment: How is your map defined? `A\isomorphic B` under left-multiplication by a permutation? Or under conjugation, i.e. `B = p A inverse(p)`?

Comment: @frenk a permutation is a funtion, but not every function is a permutation.  The case {123, 111, 321} and {321, 333, 123} is not correct for my question because 111 and 333 are not permutations.

Comment: @FalconUA, In a cursory brute-force search in Haskell, I could not find a counter-example or false positive to my algorithm - since you are actually applying this, I was wondering if you might let me know if you do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very simple solution for this: transposition.

If two sets are isomorphic, it means a one-to-one mapping exists, where the set of all the numbers at index `i` in set `S1` equals the set of all the numbers at some index `k` in set `S2`. My conjecture is that no two non-isomorphic sets have this property.

(1) Jean Logeart's example:

```
0: [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
1: [[2,3,1],[1,3,2]]
2: [[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]
3: [[3,2,1],[1,2,3]]

Perform ONE pass:

Transpose, O(n):
0: [[1,3],[2,2],[3,1]]

Sort both in and between groups, O(something log something):
0: [[1,3],[1,3],[2,2]]

Hash:
"131322" -> 0

...
"121233" -> 1
"121323" -> 2
"131322" -> already hashed.

0 and 3 are isomorphic.
```

(2) vsoftco's counter-example in his comment to Jean Logeart's answer:

```
A = [ [0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1] ]
B = [ [1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1] ]

"010212" -> A
"010212" -> already hashed.

A and B are isomorphic.
```

You can turn each set into a transposed-sorted string or hash or whatever compressed object for linear-time comparison. Note that this algorithm considers all three sets `A`, `B` and `C` as isomorphic even if one `p` converts `A` to `B` and another `p` converts `A` to `C`. Clearly, in this case, there are `p`s to convert any one of these three sets to the other, since all we are doing is moving each `i` in one set to a specific `k` in the other. If, as you stated, your goal is to "remove isomorphic permutations," you will still get a list of sets to remove.

Explanation:

Assume that along with our sorted hash, we kept a record of which permutation each `i` came from. vsoftco's counter-example:

```
010212  // hash for A and B
100110  // origin permutation, set A
100110  // origin permutation, set B
```

In order to confirm isomorphism, we need to show that the `i`'s grouped in each index from the first set moved to *some* index in the second set, which index does not matter. Sorting the groups of `i`'s does not invalidate the solution, rather it serves to confirm movement/permutation between sets.

Now by definition, each number in a hash *and each number in each group in the hash* is represented in an origin permutation exactly one time for each set. However we choose to arrange the numbers in each group of `i`'s in the hash, we are guaranteed that each number in that group is representing a different permutation in the set; and the moment we theoretically assign that number, we are guaranteed it is "reserved" for that permutation and index only. For a given number, say `2`, in the two hashes, we are guaranteed that it comes from one index and permutation in set `A`, and in the second hash corresponds to one index and permutation in set `B`. That is all we really need to show - that the number in one index for each permutation in one set (a group of distinct `i`'s) went to *one index only* in the other set (a group of distinct `k`'s). Which permutation and index the number belongs to is irrelevant.

Remember that any set `S2`, isomorphic to set `S1`, can be derived from `S1` using one permutation function or various combinations of different permutation functions applied to `S1`'s members. What the sorting, or reordering, of our numbers and groups actually represents is the permutation we are choosing to assign as the solution to the isomorphism rather than an actual assignment of which number came from which index and permutation. Here is vsoftco's counter-example again, this time we will add the origin indexes of our hashes:

```
110022 // origin index set A
001122 // origin index set B
```

Therefore our [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_one-line_notation), a solution to the isomorphism, is:

[image]

Or, in order:

[image]

(Notice that in Jean Logeart's example there is more than one solution to the isomorphism.)

Comment: Your algorithm seems to work, I'm just trying to understand why :) Did you test it on some other examples with a bit more permutations?

Comment: @vsoftco according to the OP, FalconUA's, definition, "isomorphic" means one permutation function maps *all* of set `A`'s permutations to *all* of `B`'s permutations (they both contain K permutations). This means simply that each index `i` in `A`'s permutations will go to a specific index `k` in `B`'s permutations (for example, all the `S[A][1]'s` will go to `S[B][5]'s`). All we have to do is check if the grouping *by index* of permutations in `A` and `B` contain the same numbers. One easy way to do that is to sort those groupings.

Comment: Interesting! Need to think about this some more.

Comment: Hmm, your algorithm seems to work but i'm not sure about the safety of swapping first and second elements of the transposition...

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't think it works: `A = { [1,2,0,3], [3,1,0,2] }`, `B = { [2,0,3,1], [1,2,3,0] }`, and `B = [3,2,0,1]A` However the "hash"-es are: `A: 00121323`, `B: 01021233`.

Comment: @vsoftco I think your permuting is wrong: `[3,2,0,1] * { [1,2,0,3], [3,1,0,2] } => {[0,3,2,1]  [0,2,1,3]}` not `{[2,0,3,1], [1,2,3,0] }` hashes are both `00121323` and they are isomorphic

Comment: Just to make sure we use the same conventions... Isn't `[3,2,0,1] \composed [1,2,0,3] = [2,0,3,1]`? You do it starting with the right-most permutation, `0->1->2, 1->2->0, 2->0->3, 3->3->1`.

Comment: @vsoftco Not sure I understand you. What I do is apply the permutation `[3,2,0,1]` to each of `[1,2,0,3]` and `[3,1,0,2]`: for the first one, `[1,2,0,3]`: 1 goes  index 3; 2 goes to index 2; 0 goes to index 0; and 3 goes to index 1. Makes sense?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I think you're composing the in reverse http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549186/the-product-or-composition-of-permutation-groups-in-two-line-notation

Comment: vsoftco, OP never said it is a permutation product. It's just a permutation function - see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation in the section titled "Definition and one-line notation".

Comment: @FalconUA I added an explanation of why I think sorting is ok.

Comment: @AmiTavory added an explanation.

Answer (score 6):

You can sort and compare:

```
// 1 - sort each set of permutation
for i = 0 to S-1
    sort(pset[i])
// 2 - sort the array of permutations itself
sort(pset)
// 3 - compare
for i = 1 to S-1 {
    if(areEqual(pset[i], pset[i-1]))
        // pset[i] and pset[i-1] are isomorphic
}
```

### A concrete example:

```
0: [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
1: [[2,3,1],[1,3,2]]
2: [[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]
3: [[3,2,1],[1,2,3]]
```

After 1:

```
0: [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
1: [[1,3,2],[2,3,1]] // order changed
2: [[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]
3: [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]] // order changed
```

After 2:

```
2: [[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]
0: [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
3: [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]] 
1: [[1,3,2],[2,3,1]]
```

After 3:

```
(2, 0) not isomorphic 
(0, 3) isomorphic
(3, 1) not isomorphic
```

### What about the complexity?

- 1 is `O(S * (K * N) * log(K * N))`
- 2 is `O(S * K * N * log(S * K * N))`
- 3 is `O(S * K * N)`

So the overall complexity is `O(S * K * N log(S * K * N))`

Comment: I'll have to look more into these complexities: I think they are better than those.

Comment: Wow, it's a really interesting solution, and intuitively it is correct, but are you sure that if they're equal after sorting then we can say that they're "isomorphic" in the way that i've described above?

Comment: @JeanLogeart I'm not 100% convinced, you are basically multiplying with the inverse of the element in the first permutation set all of the other sets. But when there are many sets, most of them can map to something quite ugly, and I don't think that by just comparing them lexicographically you'll whether they are isomorphic.

Comment: Pretty sure. Think of your problem as the famous "anagram problem" where two words are isomorphic if they are anagram. But in your case the letters are a set of elements (array of ``int`` in your specific example)

Comment: @JeanLogeart thanks, have to think about it more. I know a sol. with `S^2 K^2 N`, but yours is better (if correct).

Comment: What about this example: `A = [ [0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1] ]`, `B = [ [1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1] ]`. Here `B = [1, 0, 2] * A`, so they are isomorphic under the OP definition. Or are you considering the mapping as taking elements of `A` under conjugation, i.e. `p A inv(p)`?

Comment: Sorry last element of `B` is `[2,1,0]`, so `B` is `[ [1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0] ]`

Comment: Why do you assume that to be isomorphic, `pset[i]` must equal `pset[i-1]` ? As  vsoftco's example of isomorphic `A = [ [0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1] ]` and `B = [ [1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1] ] = [1, 0, 2] * A` shows, your method would miss that. Or am I misunderstanding your test for `areEqual`? (Please see my answer)

Comment: @FalconUA Consider arbitrary set `S` represented as array `A`. Since order within a set doesn't matter, assume wlog that elements of `S` are sorted within the array `A`. Now consider some `A'` which is a permutation of `A`. Clearly `A'` represents the same set as `S` since all we did was rearrange elements. Every unsorted isomorphism of `A` can be generated by some permutation. If instead we have an unsorted array `B`, we can sort it into `B'`. If `B' = A`, then clearly `B` is a permutation of `A`, so `B` also represents the set `S`. If `B' != A`, then `B` is not a permutation of `A`.

Answer (score 4):

Take `a0` in `A`. Then find it's inverse (fast, `O(N)`), call it `a0inv`. Then choose some `i` in `B` and define `P_i = b_i * ainv` and check that `P_i * a` generates `B`, when varying `a` over `A`. Do this for every `i` in B. If you don't find any `i` for which the relation holds, then the sets are not isomorphic. If you find such an `i`, then the sets are isomorphic. The runtime is `O(K^2)` for each pair of sets it checks, and you'd need to check `O(S^2)` sets, so you end up with `O(S^2 * K^2 * N)`.

PS: I assumed here that by "*maps A to B*" you mean mapping under permutation composition, so `P(a)` is actually the permutation `P` composed with the permutation `a`, and I've used the fact that if `P` is a permutation, then there must exist an `i` for which `Pa = b_i` for some `a`.

**EDIT** I decided to undelete my answer as I am not convinced the previous one (@Jean Logeart) based on searching is correct. If yes, I'll gladly delete mine, as it performs worse, but I think I have a counterexample, see the comments below Jean's answer.

Comment: Yes, I think your counter-example to Jean Logeart's answer is correct. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that two elements of *s1, s2 \in S* are isomorphic. Then if *p1* and *p2* are permutations, then *s1* is isomorphic to *s2* iff *p1(s1)* is isomorphic to *p2(s2)* where *pi(si)* is the set of permutations obtained by applying *pi* to every element in *si*.

For each *i in 1...s* and *j in 1...k*, choose the *j-th* member of *si*, and find the permutation that changes it to unity. Apply it to all the elements of *si*. Hash each of the *k* permutations to a number, obtaining *k* numbers, for any choice of *i* and *j*, at cost *nk*.

Comparing the hashed sets for two different values of *i* and *j* is *k^2 < nk*. Thus, you can find the set of candidate matches at cost *s^2 k^3 n*. If the actual number of matches is low, the overall complexity is far beneath what you specified in your question.

Comment: I think I found a logarithmic time solution.

Comment: Cool! You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

To check if two sets **S₁** and **S₂** are isomorphic you can do a much shorter search.

If they are isomorphic then there is a permutation **t** that maps each element of **S₁** to an element of **S₂**; to find **t** you can just pick any fixed element **p** of **S₁** and consider the permutations

```
 t₁ = (1/p) q₁
 t₂ = (1/p) q₂
 t₃ = (1/p) q₃
 ...
```

for all elements **q** of **S₂**. For, if a valid **t** exists then it must map the element **p** to an element of **S₂**, so only permutations mapping **p** to an element of **S₂** are possible candidates.

Moreover given a candidate **t** to check if two sets of permutations **S₁t** and **S₂** are equal you could use an hash computed as the x-or of an hash code for each element, doing the full check of all the permutations only if the hash matches.